# Mobile and desktop web app with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to build two versions of my project for mobile and desktop.
Am working codeigniter 2.0.2, am looking for a way for the mobile and desktop versions of the project to share the same model, controllers, libraries, and helpers.
Also i have set up a sub-domain,m.xyz.com to point to folder called "m" on public_html folder,
i want the the mobile to be in the "m" folder and share resources with the desktop app residing in root so i dont create duplicate models, controllers etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter allows you to specify the folder that you are loading your views from.  Since you want to reuse all of your application code, simply set up CodeIgniter so that it is loading mobile optimized views rather than the default (desktop) views.

1. Copy the root `index.php` file into the `/m/` folder that you created.
2. Update the `$system_path` and `$application_folder` variables in `/m/index.php` with the correct paths.
3. Update the `$view_folder` variable in `/m/index.php` with the path to your view folder containing your mobile optimized views.

You mobile site will now mirror your desktop site - it will just be pulling in different views.

Note that the structure of your mobile views folder will need to mirror the structure of your default views folder.

**EDIT:** The `$view_folder` option will not be available until version 2.1.  Here is the code if you wish to make the change yourself:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/8eef9c77512d4fad5357d3cbda83b89f844d7d16

Comment: I cant find the $view_folder variable in the index.php

Comment: i cant seem to find the $view_folder variable in the index.php page

Comment: What version of CI are you using?

Comment: It looks like it was added in 2.0.3.  I would recommend upgrading (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_203.html), otherwise you'll have to extend the core.

Comment: still cant find it in the index.php file of version 2.0.3

Comment: You're right.  It was added in September and will be available in 2.1.  If you interested in editing the core you can see what you'll need to do at https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/8eef9c77512d4fad5357d3cbda83b89f844d7d16.

Comment: yeah i just saw the commit on github, i've edited my core. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: why not just using a different folder in /view?

Comment: With my approach you don't need to change *any* controller code.  If you use a different folder then you need to wrap each `$this->load->view()` in a conditional...