# Desktop and Mobile versions with HMVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, mobile, hmvc

I wish to create a desktop and a mobile version of a site using HMVC in CodeIgniter.

This is similar to this question:

[Mobile and desktop web app with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604008/mobile-and-desktop-web-app-with-codeigniter)

but differs in that my views are stored in individual module directories which makes it difficult to change only the view path as suggested.

### The Question:

How do I crate a mobile version of a site using the exact same controller logic as the desktop version, but  with different views while using HMVC?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Colin I have updated the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');

if($this->agent->is_mobile())
{
   //send to mobile theme
}
```