# how to create mobile web aplication in codeigniter framework?

Tags: codeigniter, mobile, web

I want to create a mobile application website (m.example.com). before I make the web using CodeIgniter framework (CI). like where a great solution to add m.example.com in Framwork CodeIgniter ??

thanks for the response has been simply and solutions

Answer (score 0):

> I get your point, But I suggest you to this link as reference

[Mobile and desktop web app with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604008/mobile-and-desktop-web-app-with-codeigniter)